# How do I pass a querystring that has spaces or periods to a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-routing, query-string

Hello fellow programmers,

I'm struggling with my MVC Application.  I have a querystring I want to pass to my controller, let's call it "Happy Days" however when the string is passed in from my view it will only pass in "Happy" and stop because there is a space.  In the same manner if the string was "Happy.Days" it would only pass in "Happy" and stop at the period.

My questions is how do I pass the full string in and include the space or periods?

The string is passed in from a client template within a Kendo grid, here is the code that I have in my client template for handling that.  Even if this was done in another manner the space would still be a problem however this is so that you can see my scenario.

```
"<a data-identity='#=owner_company#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='\\#owner_details' href='" + Url.Action("OwnerModal", "Home") + "/" + Server.UrlEncode("#=owner_company#") + "'>#=owner_company#</a>");
```

You'll see that I have attempted to use URLEncode but this hasn't helped.

The URL that is contructed in the view is as follows:

```
<a href="/Project/Home/Owner/Happy Days" data-target="#owner_details" data-toggle="modal" data-identity="modal">Happy Days</a>
```

As you can see it's got the string with the space in it as expected.

Is there anyway I can fix this or encode it correctly in my view for passing to the controller.

Thanks

Comment: "You'll see that I have attempted to use URLEncode but this hasn't helped." Really?  What poops out the other end?

Comment: Ok so if I pass "Happy Days" with URLEncode the controller still only gets "Happy".

Comment: But what gets pooped out in the UI?  You should be able to inspect the anchor tag and see what the URL is.

Comment: poop poop poop (see, first thing is to verify your URL is correct in the UI. Next is to take a look at the controller method.  Figure out where in the postback this is going south. Poop.)

Comment: Ahh my apologise I misunderstood you there.  Here is the URL thats contructed in the view.  It's exactly as I expect it to be and you'll note that the string is there with a space.  

<a href="/Project/Home/Owner/Happy Days" data-target="#owner_details" data-toggle="modal" data-identity="modal">Happy Days</a>

Comment: You are encoding your string server side, but the model is available only client side. So you are encoding "#=owner_company#" and not "Happy Days". I recommend you to use some kind of client side method to encode your query string parameter.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma The rendering happens on the server before it's sent down the tubes.  Look at his edit--the URL is, in fact, rendered.  The problem is that it isn't encoded correctly.

Comment: @Will are you sure about that? I'm no Kendo UI expert, but looking at documentation it's clear that `#=...#` strings are rendered by javascript client-side: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I'm not either, but I'm damn near expert at reading.  **"The URL that is contructed in the view is as follows: `<a href="/Project/Home/Owner/Happy Days"`"**  That looks like it's rendered properly, just not encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to this:

```
"<a data-identity='#=owner_company#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='\\#owner_details' href='" + Url.Action("OwnerModal", "Home") + "/#= encodeURIComponent(owner_company) #"'>#=owner_company#</a>");
```

This way you encode the URI parameter with `#= encodeURIComponent(owner_company) #` client-side with javascript, which is the proper way of doing it since Kendo UI uses a client-side templating system.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `Server.UrlEncode` sucks.  It isn't encoding the space, which is causing your headaches server side.  Some preliminary research suggests its existence is for backwards compatibility, which may be why it fails so hard.

Instead, you should use `Uri.EscapeUriString()`.

```
<a href='" + 
    Url.Action("OwnerModal", "Home") + 
    "/" +
    Uri.EscapeUriString("#=owner_company#") + 
    "'>#=owner_company#</a>
```

(`Uri.EscapeUriString("#=owner_company#")` looks weird to me, but if it works, knock yourself out. If not, ... fix it?)

Comment: I found something interesting our over the weekend regarding this.  I have included 'data-toggle' and 'data-target' in my url which is for the Bootstrap 3 modal popup.  If I take those items out of the url and the string is passed in correctly.  I narrowed it down even further and it's this item "data-toggle='modal'" specifically that's stopping the string being passed correctly.  Remove this and it works, not the best considering I need the modal.